# Increasing the space between the bars in histplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I have plotted a simple histogram using Seaborn but the bars are stuck together and I would like to increase the space between them.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot([-2.0, -1.0, -2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 4.0])
```

[image]

I tried a couple of suggestions such as adding `rwidth` argument or using `rwidth` within `hist_kws` argument but neither worked for histplot.

Comment: Maybe you want `discrete=True`?

Comment: @JohanC No, when yous set discrete to True, it "draws the bars so that they are
    centered on their corresponding data points". It does not increase the space between the bars

Comment: So, maybe you want `shrink=0.8`? It could be confusing, as the extra white space might suggest that the bars don't include those x values.

Comment: @JohanC The combination of  ```discrete=True``` and ```shrink=0.8``` works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to get some spaces between your bins, without actually changing their sizes. I would play with style and linewidth in this case:

```py
sns.set_style("white")
sns.histplot([-2.0, -1.0, -2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -3.0, -2.0, 4.0], linewidth=5.0)
```

Output:

[image]